# Create a random selection weighted on number of points, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of winners for a prize draw, where each winner has earned a number of points over the year. There are 1300 registered users, with points varying between 50 and 43,000. I need to be able to select a random winner, which is straight forward, but the challenge I am having is building the logic where each point counts as an entry ticket into the prize draw. Would appreciate any help.

John

Comment: Can you provide a simple schema and sample data?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script would look something similar to this:

Script 1 :

```
DECLARE @Name   varchar(100),
@Points int,
@i      int


DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Name, Points FROM Table1

OPEN Cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1
INTO @Name, @Points
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @i = 0

  WHILE @i < @Points
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Table2 (Name)
     VALUES (@Name)
     SET @i = @i + 1
   END

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @Name, @Points
 END
DEALLOCATE Cursor1
```

I have created a table (Table1) with only a Name and Points column (varchar(100) and int), I have created a cursor in order to look through all the records within Table1 and then loop through the Points and then inserted each record into another table (Table2).

This then imports the Name depending on the Points column.

Script 2 :

```
DECLARE @Name   varchar(100),
        @Points int,
        @i      int,
        @Count  int


CREATE TABLE #temptable(
UserEmailID nvarchar(200),
Points int)

DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT UserEmailID, Points FROM Table1_TEST

OPEN Cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1
INTO @Name, @Points
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @i = 0
    WHILE @i < @Points
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #temptable (UserEmailID, Points)
            VALUES (@Name, @Points)
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END


FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @Name, @Points
END
DEALLOCATE Cursor1

SELECT * FROM #temptable
DROP TABLE #temptable
```

In Script2 I have imported the result into a TEMP table as requested.
The script now runs through each record within you Table1 and imports the individuals UserEmailID and Points into the TEMP table depending on how much the Points are in Table1.

So if John has a total of 3 points, and Sarah 2, the script will import Johns UserEmailID 3 times into the TEMP table and 2 times for Sarah.

If you apply the random selector on the TEMP table, it will then randomly select a individual.
John would obviously stand a better chance to win because he has 3 records in the TEMP table whereas Sarah only has 2.

Suppose Johns UserEmailID is 1 and Sarah is 2:
The OUTPUT of TEMP table would then be:

```
UserEmailID   |  Points
1             | 3
1             | 3
1             | 3
2             | 2
2             | 2
```

Please let me know if you need any clarity.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @PKirby and thanks for your help. I modified the script to include the appropriate table and column names, but I am getting a few errors. The stage I am at at the moment is that I have a #temptable containing UserEmailID and Points columns. The top 5 columns look something like this;

Comment: Hi @JohnMiller , I have created Table1 and Table2 only to test my script but this should work fine with a TEMP table. If you can let me know what columns exist in your Table and what columns you would like in your TEMP table, I can rewrite my script accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your help. I edited the script to include the appropriate table and columns, but I am getting a few errors. I have a #temptable with UserEmailID and Points columns. The top 3 rows look something like this;

UserEmailID            Points
me@me.com              43567
john@smith.co.uk       38562
jon.consumer@buy.com   36753

A query on the #temptable returns the following;

Rows = 1344
Total Points = 1726316

This is a draw where we have to select 1 random winner, where the points accrued from each UserEmailID equates to the number of tickets in the hat.

Comment: The formatting might not be great, there are 2 column names, UserEmailID and Points.

Comment: @JohnMiller, please see updated script and discription.

Comment: Edited a bit as #temptable already exists

`DECLARE @Name   varchar(100),
        @Points int,
        @i      int,
        @Count  int

DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT UserEmailID, Points FROM #temptable

OPEN Cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1
INTO @Name, @Points
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @i = 0
    WHILE @i < @Points
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #temptable (UserEmailID, Points)
            VALUES (@Name, @Points)
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END


FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @Name, @Points
END
DEALLOCATE Cursor1

SELECT * FROM #temptable
DROP TABLE #temptable`

Comment: @JohnMiller ,  Table1_TEST represents your table where the UserEmailID and Points columns sit. After the cursor fetches the first record, It imports the UserEmailID and Points as many times as what the Points column states into the TEMP table, in this case called #temptable. You need to updated Table1_TEST to whatever your table name is.

If you get an error that reads : "There is already an object named '#temptable' in the database." just run your DROP statement : DROP TABLE #temptable

Comment: Please provide me with your table name and columns and example data within that table together with your script so far. I will alter the script so that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a weighted draw using the following method:

- Calculate the cumulative sum of points.
- Divide by the total number of points to get a value between 0 and 1
- Each row in the original data will have a range, such as [0, 0.1), [0.1, 0.3), [0.3, 1]
- Calculate a random number and choose the row where the value falls in the range

Here is standard'ish SQL for this approach:

```
with u as (
      select u.*,
             coalesce(lead(rangestart) over (order by points) as rangeend, 1)
      from (select u.*,
                   sum(points*1.0) over (order by points) / sum(points) over () as rangestart
            from users u
           ) u
     ),
     r as (
      select random() as rand
     )
select u.*
from u
where r.rand between rangestart and rangeend;
```

In addition to using window functions (which can be handled by correlated subqueries in many cases), the exact format depends on whether the random number generator is deterministic for a query (such as SQL Server where `random()` returns one value no matter how often called in a query) or non-deterministic (such as in other databases).  This method only requires one value for the random number generator, so it will work with either method.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a winner with 1000 points have double the chances as another with only 500 points.

Sort the winners by whatever order and create a running total for the points:

```
id       points
winner1  100
winner2  50
winner3  150
```

gives:

```
id       points    from  to
winner1  100         1   100
winner2   50       101   150
winner3  150       151   300
```

Then compare with a random number from 1 to sum(points), in the example a number between 1 and 300. Find the winner with that number range and you're done.

```
select winpoints.id_winner
from
(
  select 
    id as id_winner,
    coalesce(sum(points) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) + 1 as from_points,
    sum(points) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as to_points
  from winners
) winpoints
where (select floor(rand() * (sum(points) from winners)) + 1)
      between winpoints.from_points and winpoints.to_points;
```

Comment: That's about right. It's like  raffle, where the number of points for each entrant equals the number of tickets in the hat. The more points (raffle tickets) the more chances of winning.

Comment: Good, so I understood the task correctly and my solution works. When drawing a random number from 1 to 300 in my example, it is of course double as likely to be in the range from 1 to 100 than from 101 to 150. So winner1 has twice as many chances to win as winner2, because he/she has twice as many points.

Comment: I'll test the code tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help today.

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works with fractional points/weights. It creates a helper table `usersum`.

```
create table user (id int primary key, points float);
insert into user values (1, 0.5), (2, 0), (3, 1);

create table usersum (id int primary key, pointsum float);
insert into usersum
select id, (select sum(points) from user b where b.id <= a.id)
from user a;

set @r = rand() * (select max(pointsum) from usersum);
select @r, usersum.* from usersum where pointsum >= @r order by id limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae539e/1